# Transfer to data in right place in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below. My aim is to **count** apple and mango under fruit.

I want to do this using case when statement. I run this query but it didn't work.

This works:

```
CASE 
    WHEN Food_type = 'vegetables' 
         AND Names IN ('apple', 'mango') 
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
END IN (0)


CASE 
    WHEN Names IN ('apple', 'orange', 'mango') 
       THEN 'fruit' 
END Food_type2
```

Output:

| Names | Food_type |
| --- | --- |
| apple | vegetables |
| eggplant | vegetables |
| carrot | vegetables |
| orange | fruit |
| onion | vegetables |
| spinach | vegetables |
| mango | vegetables |

How can I do this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This? Sample data till line #9; query begins at line #10.

```
SQL> with test (names, food_type) as
  2    (select 'apple'   , 'vegetables' from dual union all
  3     select 'eggplant', 'vegetables' from dual union all
  4     select 'carrot'  , 'vegetables' from dual union all
  5     select 'orange'  , 'fruit'      from dual union all
  6     select 'onion'   , 'vegetables' from dual union all
  7     select 'spinach' , 'vegetables' from dual union all
  8     select 'mango'   , 'vegetables' from dual
  9    )
 10  select case when names in ('apple', 'mango') or food_type = 'fruit' then 'fruit'
 11              else 'vegetables'
 12         end food_type,
 13         count(*)
 14  from test
 15  group by
 16         case when names in ('apple', 'mango') or food_type = 'fruit' then 'fruit'
 17              else 'vegetables'
 18         end;

FOOD_TYPE    COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
vegetables          4
fruit               3

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for solution. But i don't understand that why we used 'case when statement' twice?
why we don't write like this ? 'group by food_type'

Comment: Because you have to GROUP BY by column(s) not being aggregated, and - in this case - it is the whole CASE expression.